# How can I make a regex that matches any combination of "<br>", "<br/>", and "<p>" that appears at the start of a line?

Tags: regex

I want to match all "new line" type html tags (breaks and paragraphs) **no matter how many** and in what order they appear, so long as they appear at the beginning of a line.

This regex pattern matches the **first** one:
    `^<[Bb][Rr] ?/?>|^<[Pp]>`

So, given this text `<p><br>fred`, it would match the first `<p>` but not the immediately following `<br>` also.

Note that I don't want to remove every one of these tags, but only those which appear at the beginning of the input line.

Comment: joeframbach is referring to [this famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), in case you weren't aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also add support for white spaces between the tags:

```
^(?:(?:<[Bb][Rr]>\s*)|(?:<[Pp]\s*>))+
```

Comment: I fleshed it out a little more:  ^(?:(?:<[Bb][Rr]\s*?/?>\s*)|(?:<[Pp]?/?\s*>\s*))+

Comment: Makes sense with the optional slashes. As for `[Pp]?` - should it have been rather `[Pp]\s*?` ? Also to make it consistent in both cases this syntax could be used `\s*?/?\s*>`

Comment: So the whole thing would look like this:  `^(?:(?:<[Bb][Rr]\s*?/?\s*>\s*)|(?:<[Pp]\s*?/?\s*>\s*))+`

Answer (score 2):

You need some [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
^(<[Bb][Rr] ?/?>|^<[Pp]>)+
```

Also, this would be clearer/more concise if you just used a case-insensitivity flag instead of character classes.

```
^(<br ?/?>|^<p>)+
```

Comment: I believe there's a small typo.  Should have the final > before the final ) like this:  ^(<[Bb][Rr] ?/?>|^<[Pp]>)+